# Where should I put view related constants - backbone.js

Tags: view, constants, conventions, backbone.js

Imagine that I have a view, and as part of a view it render 'x' model objects, and 'x' only.  The question, where is it appropriate for me to put this view related constant?

My guess would be to do something like this:

```
myApp.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    myConstant: 10,
    ...
    render: function(){
        ...
        //some code that uses myConstant
        ...
    }
});
```

Does this make sense?

Any suggestions help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is to assign a class property to the view.  You can pass a second hash into your extend call to do this.  Your code would look something like this:

```
myApp.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function() {
        alert(myApp.MyView.myConstant);
    }

}, {

    myConstant: 10

});
```

where your constant is accessible as myApp.MyView.myConstant.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm accepting this, because I didn't know about class properties, but my real question was slightly different.  Not *can I do it this way*, but *should I do it this way*.  Is it considered good practise to have these types of properties just floating around?

Comment: Thanks, and totally understand.  If this were Java, you would attach a constant on the class.  Your alternative would be to set up some global constant, but then it would be global and not namespaced to the concern where it is relevant.  I would say its good practice, though I'm open to someone else's opinion.

Comment: I really like this solution. However I would add in a separate extend instead of doing it on the fly - for clarity. That's just a personal preference though.

Answer (score 5):

You're very close!  You'll actually just use this.myConstant.  Here is a working example...

```
testView = Backbone.View.extend({
    test: "hello world!",

    initialize: function(){
        alert( this.test );
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    },

    render: function(){
        //do your rendering...
        return this;
    }
});
var view = new testView();
```

Answer (score 1):

As above I agree with (and upvoted) the accepted answer however for clarity I would be tempted to go with this format:

```
myApp.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        alert(myApp.MyView);
    }
});

_.extend(myApp.MyView.prototype, {
  enum : {
      //...
  }
});
```

The reason being you might have lots of mixins for your view and I find the visibility becomes blurred when you just keep adding on object after object to View.extend. At least this way you can break it up and put comments in-between your mixins. It also makes a bit more sense if you're using RequireJS and loading in a common set of enums/mixins.

Comment: what's the proper syntax? myApp.MyView.enum is undefined as it stands.

Comment: @eugene - That's just one way of getting at it. The point is that it sits on the view instance. See omeralper's remark below about this as it might not be what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't initialize your view constants under extend, it will behave like static constant for all your view instances. Use constructor instead:

```
constructor: function()
{
     Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
     this.myConstant = 10;
     this.myOtherConstant = {};
}
```

[more explanation here](http://doginthehat.com.au/2012/02/do-not-initialise-your-subclass-properties-in-backbones-extend/)

Comment: Then just extend the instance if you don't want your constants to be part of your prototype. Normally I keep constants in separate controllers/modules (sometimes within collections).